# A strange problem encountered during training

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

A hyperlink to the paper   https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11431
A hyperlink to the code  https://github.com/sacmehta/ESPNetv2

I redesigned the network architecture by using the paper ESPNetv2's EESP module, and used it's open source code method to train the network, but there was a strange phenomenon. The miou value of the training set is constantly increasing, but the miou value of the verification set is like a Random value, the value will remain unchanged at the end of the network training and is very small !

```
Parameters: 317052

Epoch   Loss(Tr)    Loss(val)   mIOU (tr)   mIOU (val   

0       0.9102      2.3089      0.2807      0.0208  

1       0.7575      3.2041      0.3170      0.0135  

2       0.6914      2.9142      0.3383      0.0273  

3       0.6619      3.5181      0.3469      0.0130  

4       0.6431      3.2931      0.3555      0.0160  

5       0.6274      3.8645      0.3601      0.0237  

6       0.6175      3.1952      0.3643      0.0266
```

Comment: Could you please add a hyperlink to the paper?

Comment: Added at the beginning of the question